# Searching min and max in list of numbers

Tags: c++, loops, max, min

I must write a program, which reads in loop a list of numbers, until user give number 0. Number 0 is not included in calculations, is only signal for end data. Next program write min and max element from string of numbers, and how many times it was entered. For example for (2,3,1,5,4,2,3,1,5,1)

Min 1 3 times

Max 5 2 times

I have problem with **number**, cause when I have **max** and enter lower numbers my **lmax** is getting higher. Second problem is program don't respond on '0'. What am I doing wrong?

```
int number;
int min = 0;
int max = 0;
int lmin = 1;
int lmax = 1;
do {
    cout << "Number: ";
    cin >> number;

    if (min == 0 && max == 0) {
        min = number;
        max =  number;
    }

    else if (number > max && number !=0) {
        max = number;
        lmax = 1;
    }
    else if (number < min && number != 0) {
        min = number;
        lmin = 1;
    }
    else if (number = max) {
        lmax++;
    }
    else if (number = min) {
        lmin++;
    }


    } while (number != 0);

    cout << "Min " << min << " " << lmin << " times" <<endl;
    cout << "Max " << max << " " << lmax << " times" << endl;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `=` rather than `==` for portions of your solution. Try changing

```
else if (number = max) {
```

to something like

```
else if (number == max) {
```

Comment: This mistake also implies that compiler warnings are either turned off or they are being ignored.